Problem with OPC UA Client (async handling) and GUI Interaction
I'm working on developing an OPC UA client with a GUI interface. I've successfully connected to the server and interacted with it within the main loop. However, when I try to call methods via a class that manages the GUI, I encounter exceptions without any error messages.
Currently, I try to get running the List Namespace Button.
Here's version of my code:

import asyncio
import tkinter as tk
from asyncua import Client
import threading
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Adresse des OPC UA Servers
SERVER_URL = "opc.tcp://localhost:4840/freeopcua/server/"
NAMESPACE_URI = "http//freeopcua/defaults/modeler"

class OpcuaClient:
    def __init__(self, server_url):
        self.client = Client(server_url)

    async def connect(self):
        try:
            await self.client.connect()
            print("Verbunden mit dem OPC UA Server.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Fehler beim Verbinden mit dem OPC UA Server: {e}")

    async def disconnect(self):
        try:
            await self.client.disconnect()
            print("Verbindung zum OPC UA Server getrennt.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Fehler beim Trennen von dem OPC UA Server: {e}")

    async def get_node(self, node_id):
        try:
            return self.client.get_node(node_id)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Fehler beim Abrufen des Knotens: {e}")
            return None

    async def set_valve(self, valve_id, state):
        try:
            node = await self.get_node(f"ns=2;s=Valve_{valve_id}.State")  # Ändere den Node Identifier entsprechend
            if node:
                await node.set_value(state)
                print(f"Ventil {valve_id} Zustand gesetzt auf {state}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Fehler beim Setzen des Zustands von Ventil {valve_id}: {e}")

    async def list_namespaces(self):
        try:
            print("list_namespaces => start")
            print(self.client.description)
            await self.client.check_connection()
            
            namespaces = await self.client.get_namespace_array()
            print("Namespaces auf dem Server:")
            for idx, namespace in enumerate(namespaces):
                print(f"Namespace {idx}: {namespace}")
            return namespaces
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Fehler beim Abrufen der Namespaces: {e}")
            return []

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, opcua_client: OpcuaClient, loop):
        super().__init__()
        self.opcua_client = opcua_client
        self.loop = loop
        self.title("OPC UA Client")
        self.geometry("300x300")

        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(1, 5):
            button = tk.Button(self, text=f"Toggle Valve {i}", command=lambda i=i: self.toggle_valve(i))
            button.pack(pady=10)
            self.buttons.append(button)

        self.namespace_button = tk.Button(self, text="List Namespaces", command=self.list_namespaces)
        self.namespace_button.pack(pady=10)

    def toggle_valve(self, valve_number):
        print(f"Button für Ventil {valve_number} geklickt.")
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.opcua_client.set_valve(valve_number, not state), self.loop)

    def list_namespaces(self):
        print("list_namespaces")
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.opcua_client.list_namespaces(), self.loop)

async def main(loop):
    opcua_client = OpcuaClient(SERVER_URL)
    await opcua_client.connect()

    idx = await opcua_client.client.get_namespace_array()
    _logger.info("index of our namespace is %s", idx)

    await opcua_client.list_namespaces()

    app = Application(opcua_client, loop)
    app.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(on_closing(app, opcua_client), loop))
    app.mainloop()

async def on_closing(app, opcua_client):
    await opcua_client.disconnect()
    app.destroy()

def start_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    threading.Thread(target=start_loop, args=(loop,), daemon=True).start()
    asyncio.run(main(loop))

In the above code, connecting and interacting with the OPC UA server directly within the main function works fine. However, when I encapsulate the GUI logic into the Application class and try to interact with the OPC UA client through button callbacks (list_namespaces), I encounter exceptions without any specific error messages.
What could be causing this issue? How can I properly handle interactions between the GUI and OPC UA client methods?

How do you know that you got exception? Which line made problem? Maybe first run code without try/excpet to see full error message. We can't run your code, we can't see what you get on your screen, and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question (not in comments) as text (rather not images)
